# Getting login error while publishing local asp.net MVC application to azure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

I have a asp.net MVC application which works fine on localhost (I am using LocalDb for the same). Here is the connection string:

```
<add name="AppContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName=|DataDirectory|\SlackApi.mdf;Initial Catalog=SlackApi;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

And here is my DbContext class :

```
public class AppContext : DbContext
{
    public AppContext() : base("AppContext")
    {
     ....
```

Today, I was trying to publish this on my azure subscription. For this I created a sample website and a sql database. I got the connection string and I simply replaced the above LocalDb connection string with this new value:

```
<add name="AppContext" connectionString="Server=tcp:pankaj.database.windows.net,1433;Database=SlackApi;User ID=pankaj@pankaj;Password={mypassword$};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I didn't change the name of the connection string, since I didn't want to modify the code and I was thinking that it would work automatically. 
But, with this change I am getting error while connecting to database:

> Login failed for user - 'pankaj'

However, If I check the sql server connection tab from Visual Studio and Do 'Test connection', it works.

This is the first time I am working with asp.net and azure and hence not sure what I am missing here.

Comment: which azure portal do you use?  `manage.windowsazure.com`, or `portal.azure.com`?

Comment: Did you replace the password in the connection string for azure?

Comment: @RoteS, yes I did.

Answer (score 0):

As can be seen from your connection string you are using `localDB` as data storage but `localDB` doesn't gets published while publishing to Azure. That's why facing the error.

```
connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)
```

Try changing your connection string to

```
connectionString="Server=pankaj.database.windows.net;Database=SlackApi;User ID=pankaj@pankaj;Password={mypassword$};Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Are you saying that perhaps the OP didn't actually migrate his local db to azure?

Comment: @SamIam, NO, rather saying that localDB doesn't gets published at all or properly. Data storage should move to proper DB installation instance.

Comment: It looks like the OP did change the connection string for the move to azure

Answer (score 0):

The connection string seems fine. One possible reason is that the published connection string is different from that you specified in your web.config, which means the connetion string is replaced with other value when publishing. You can check your publish profile and see whether the connection string is exactly the same. If not, just uncheck **Use this connection string at runtime** option.
[image]

Comment: is it in someway related to migrations ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being so lame..

The mistake I did was that I copy pasted the connection string as it is:

```
"...;Password={your password here};..."
```

And I simply replaced the 'your password here' with my password and missed removing '{' and '}'. After removing those curly braces - it works just fine.